# Why arrays in javascript are not fixed length?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In JAVA, an array is always of a fixed length. If we want a dynamic array, we use ArrayList. But it seems in javascript, arrays can be incremented and decremented dynamically using `push()` and `pop()`. Is there a reason why arrays a re handled differently in javascript? Is the reason this: fixed length arrays are dispensable...i.e there is no situation which cannot be covered by a dynamic array?

Comment: Arrays aren't even arrays in JS, they're just objects with special properties.

Comment: Why should they be fixed length?

Comment: The lesson to be learned here is that Java is in now way at all JavaScript. Might as well ask why a Weiss terminal has a different interface than an iPad

Comment: For javascript arrays closer to the arrays you were thinking about, please have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Typed_arrays

Answer (score 3):

> *"In JAVA, an array is always of a fixed length... Is there a reason why arrays a re handled differently in javascript?"*

Sure. It's an entirely different language. Arrays are objects, and objects have no concept of length.

Comment: JavaScript arrays are more like Java's Collections

Comment: Reminds me of this quote: "Java is to JavaScript like ham is to hamster."

Comment: *Arrays are objects, and objects have no concept of length.* Then, why does it have a length property?

Comment: @NoobUnChained: Because an Array is a special type of object. You can add a `.length` property to an object too. True that the `.length` of an Array has some magic behaviors, but then an Array also has a different prototype chain. I'm not saying they're identical in all ways. I'm just saying that an Array's implementation has the same core as an object

Comment: ...put it this way, the `.length` of an Array is in no way an indicator of the actual size in memory of the Array. You can have a `.length === 1000` on an Array that has only one member.